# Google Maps android api 2: The default markers are not clickable

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

In my app the default markers are not clickable (in comparison to google maps installed in the device which a balloon is showed up). Is this the normal behaviour?

How to get the default behaviour with the balloon showed on click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These markers won't be clickable. Showing info window for them is disabled for us. There is also a bug related to them: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5062

Comment: Oh thanks! So do I have to add my custom markers for each station?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have set a title for your marker. If there is no title, no "bubble" pops up.
Try `yourMarker.setTitle("Hello World!");`

Comment: This is not the case. I am referring to google's markers such as station markers etc...